# How to make a SUM of TIME (HH:MM) Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a "small" problem. I have a `SQLiteDatabase` ("PLB") with a table called "Flights". In this table i have a column called `"Total_Flight_Time"`type TIME which memorize time in `HH:MM format`. I wanna make a SUM of the hours and minutes. Something like `01:20 + 01:50 = 03:10 (HH:MM)` but i don't know how to do it.

I found a code here, on stackoverflow:
Function from DBAdapter:

```
public Cursor getTotalTime() throws SQLException {
return db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(strftime('H%:%M', Total_Flight_Time) - strftime('H%:%M', '00:00')), 'unixepoch' FROM Flights",null);
        }
```

Function call in main activity (it should show the SUM result in a Text View):

```
DBHelper.open();
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView22);
String total = DBHelper.getTotalTime().toString();
txt.setText(total);
```

But on the Screen it shows: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41aa42b8`

How do i have to do the function and the function call to fix the problem, i wan it to show HH:MM? :)

**SOLVED!
SOLUTION:**

*DBAdapter function:*

```
public Cursor getTotalTime() throws SQLException {
return db.rawQuery("SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s', Total_Flight_Time) - strftime('%s','00:00:00')),'unixepoch') FROM Flights",null);

}
```

*Function Call in Main Activity:*

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView22);
        Cursor c = DBHelper.getTotalTime();

         c.moveToFirst();
         String[] names = c.getColumnNames(); // inspect this as it should have a length of 1
                 String total = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(names[0]));

        txt.setText(total);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had you do - that is the code I wrote - why did you tell me that it did not work?

Comment: ... or acknowledge my answer

Comment: I added "time()" before sum
If i add "AS time" is not working
I mean that if i try as you wrote is not working also, i had to use "%s" if i use "%H:%M" is not showing the correct answer.

The Function Call that YOU WROTE is CORRECT :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.rawQuery(...)` returns type `Cursor` so you are calling `cursor.toString()` which results in what you see. You need to use a function of the `Cursor` class to extract the results of your query and then display the results. eg:

you may have to move the cursor to the first row in which case it will look like this:

> Cursor c = DBHelper.getTotalTime();
> c.moveToFirst();
> String total = c.getString(0);

if you dont know the column index (and its not 0) try:

> > Cursor c = DBHelper.getTotalTime();
> > c.moveToFirst();
> > String[] names = c.getColumnNames() // inspect this as it should have a length of 1
> > String total = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(names[0]));

If names.length != 1 let me know the results.

I think this (or some variation of this) should help. See the documentaion of the Cursor class for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

#### comment response:

> c.moveToFirst();
> while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
>
> > Log.w("query Test", "result: " + cur.getString(0);
> > c.moveToNext();
> > }

Comment: changed it to getString(18)
18 is the column ID but it crashing on start with "debuger staled"

Comment: It seems that you will only get one result from your query. Try `getString(0)` because the index refers to the column of the query result

Comment: if you have not already try using the 18 value in the new edit

Comment: I am almost certain the the problem is that an incorrect column index is being passed.

Comment: if(names.length != 1)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

it shows the toast so the lenght !=1

Comment: it looks IS CRASHING ON THIS
txt.setText(total);

Comment: try chaging your query to `"SELECT sum(strftime('H%:%M', Total_Flight_Time) - strftime('H%:%M', '00:00')) AS time, 'unixepoch' FROM Flights"` and then c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnIndex("time")) - this replaces names[0]

Comment: ok, some progress :)
it is not crushing but the textview text is "" so the textview is empty

Comment: you will have to tell me what development environment you are using

Comment: Eclipse under Fedora Linux. If you wan i can give you an TeamViewer ID and Password to see how it look in the compiler, maybe it helps you and me:)

Comment: No, that is fine. print the results of the query to the catlog

Comment: Do you know what the catlog is?

Comment: This tells me there is a problem with your query. To test your code i would construct a simple query that and run it through your code. If the expected value shows in the textView or in the catlog then it will be confirmed that your query is the problem

Comment: give me an email address and i'll send you the DBAdapter. I'm a beginner in Java and SQL
EDIT: Or can you give me the query and where i have to put it in my DBAdapter?

Comment: change your query to "SELECT * FROM Flights" and run the log loop in the answer

Comment: i found the problem
if i use "%s" insted of "%H:%M" it shows the secounds
but now, how do i convert the secounds in HH:MM? :|

Comment: So now when you run the code you see in the logcat a value? what is that value?

Comment: yes
i just reedited the code in dbadapter 
"SELECT sum(strftime('%H:%M:%S', Total_Flight_Time) - strftime('%H:%M:S', '00:00:00')) AS time, 'unixepoch' FROM Flights"

now i have the correct numbers of houres (12) but no :MM :|

Comment: are you missing a % sign between M:S on the second strftime(...)

Comment: added but still the same :|
EDIT: Added: 10:00:00
10:59:00
00:01:00
the result is "20" :|

Comment: try "SELECT sum(strftime('%H:%M:%S', Total_Flight_Time)) AS time, 'unixepoch' FROM Flights"

Comment: i have a problem regarding the code. The result of SUM won't show more than 24h. What to do?
I mean that if i add 23:59:59 and 23:59:59 it will show 20:59:58 :| How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the source of your problems:

> In this table i have a column called "Total_Flight_Time" type TIME which memorize time in HH:MM format.

You're misusing `TIME` data type because your `Total_Flight_Time` is actually storing a duration, not a point in time. Change the type for `Total_Flight_Time` to `integer`, representing the number of seconds or the number of minutes in the duration. Then summing up your durations become a trivial matter of integer sums. A little arithmetic will allow you to transform number of seconds/minute to days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE ME SOME DETAILS?
I changed data type to INTEGER. Now what i have to write? :)

Comment: @losif: read [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server). The latter part of the article talks about storing duration with TIME/DATETIME type and the complexity of doing so correctly, I'd recommend not to do that. Instead, the earlier part of the article describes how to store duration as integer number of seconds, once you get the basic idea, you should be able to modify it to store number of minutes if you don't need per second resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
Date curDate = formatter.parse(DBHelper.getTotalTime().toString());
long curMillis = curDate.getTime();
```

Then, you can add this to some other date (again converting that to long) and display the sum in the date format.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Comment: Don't import `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Can you write the final source because i'm very confused :((

Comment: You can try converting `java.sql.date` to `java.util.date` using this:
`java.util.Date newDate = result.getTimestamp("VALUEDATE");`

Comment: i don't understand anymore.... so what is the good code from all this topic and what is the unusefull code?

Comment: I was just suggesting, how you can sum up two date objects.

Comment: I found the solution, i will add it to the question :D